# How to automatically (programmatically) train the Knowledge Base?

Tags: api, azure-cognitive-services, knowledge-base-population

In the [QnA Maker](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/qnamaker) Service provided by the [Microsoft's Cognitive Services](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/), we can train our KB (Knowledge Base) by manually inserting the QnA pairs.

Is there a way to automate this process so that we can always keep our KB up-to-date please? There is an API documentation but i cannot find one for this purpose.

Please advise. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: See https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/ApiReference. There are APIs to programmatically manage your KB.

Comment: if i am not wrong, question is related to training model, when link has been established between question and answer while testing within QnA portal. I am not sure, but are you looking for something like this [Train API_Active learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base#train-api)

Answer (score 1):

V2 of the QnA Maker API provides the following to help you programmatically train the knowledge base:

- POST Create Knowledge Base
- DELETE Delete Knowledge Base
- GET Download Alterations
- GET Download Knowledge Base
- POST Generate answer
- PUT Publish Knowledge Base
- PATCH Train Knowledge Base
- PATCH Update Alterations
- PATCH Update Knowledge Base

For more information, see the documentation here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9baa